# How do I get all invoices for a customer using the Linq extensions in QuickBooks Online API v3?

Tags: linq, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I would like to query for all invoices in a customer. The SDK has some LinqExtender extensions so one would think you could do (for example customer id '1' which maps to an existing customer):

```
CreateQueryService<IppData.Invoice>().Where(x => x.CustomerRef.Value = "1")
```

But, this produces the following SQL:

```
Select * FROM Invoice  WHERE CustomerRef.Value = '1'
```

which is a no-go:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-08-24T13:41:04.367-07:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="4001">
      <Message>Invalid query</Message>
      <Detail>QueryValidationError: Property CustomerRef.Value not found for Entity Invoice</Detail>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

The correct SQL would read:

```
Select * FROM Invoice WHERE CustomerRef = '1'
```

Of course using SQL directly and creating dynamic queries (eww) works, but I was hoping there was a better way. I like the readability and (hopefully) type-safe-goodness of the Linq extensions, and you'd think this would be such a common thing to do. Unfortunately the documentation is a huge maze and severely lacks any kind of useful examples, so: does anyone know how to do this, or are we stuck with string SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the SDK has Linq extender extensions but this is not working as expected.
I have raised a bug for this.
Unfortunately you will have to use the regular query operations for this.

Comment: Thanks. At least I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a different library but using CustomerRef as the field and the ID as a string ended up working.  Documentation wasn't very clear on this

```
{
    field: 'CustomerRef',
    value: '2083',
    operator: '='
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using java,  i am done this and its working fine All the best:

```
 String query = select($(invoice))
                .where($(invoice.getCustomerRef().getClass().toGenericString()).eq("2"))
                .where($(invoice.getMetaData().getCreateTime()).gte(calendarStart.getTime()))
                .where($(invoice.getMetaData().getCreateTime()).lte(calendarEnd.getTime()))
                .skip(0).take(10).generate();
        QueryResult queryResultpage = service.executeQuery(query);
```